# Flush to the left align environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I would like to use the align environment within my beamer presentation, and have this flushed to the left. However, this should only be done on one frame, on the other frames I would like to keep the default settings.

How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 4):

You can made use of the `columns` environment to divide the frame into two columns and then place the `align` environment on the left column. Then it is just matter of defining the `width` of the columns to define how much equations are placed on the left.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{EastLansing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

Centered alignment:
\begin{align*}
&x+y=100\\
&z-x=10
\end{align*}

\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Left aligned equations:
\begin{align*}
&x+y=100\\
&z-x=10
\end{align*}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\vfill
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.35\textwidth}
Moreover:
\begin{align*}
&x+y=100\\
&z-x=10
\end{align*}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

will lead to:

[image]